# p-group and group actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, p-groups

$G$ is a $p$-group, which means $|G|=p^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

Now,if $p$ does not divide $|S|$, for S is a set that G acts upon, how do I show that there exists $a\in S$ such that $G_a=G$

So how do I do this, I tried to find a relation with the order of $S$ but I really don't know how.

Comment: Sorry, you know, when I think too long on something, I tend to have the illusion that the rest of the world will have to know how the prob goes and how to do it already, haha.

Comment: This is not true unless you are more specific about $a\in S$. For instance, let $C_p$ act on itself by addition, and act trivially on $\{\bullet\}$, and define $S=C_p\cup\{\bullet\}$. Then $p\nmid\#S=p+1$ but if $a\in C_p$ then ${\rm Stab}_G(a)=0\ne C_p$. Is it possible you want $p$ to not divide the *orbit* of $a$?

Comment: Your definition of $\,G_a\,$ is...weird. It doesn't need that $\,\forall g\in G\,$ inside those brackets.

Comment: I'm re-commenting due to a foolish typo I did in my last comment, which I then erased. Thanks to Anon.......The claim is almost sure false. What is true is $\,|S^G|=|S|\pmod p\,$ , with $\,S^G:=\{s\in S\;;\;gs=s\,\;\,\forall\,g\in G\}\,$

Comment: Actually, all is it asked is to show that $G_a=G$, and I thought that showing the $\forall g$ part is the way to go, it is my own claim, not the claim that I have to prove

Comment: how did you define $S^G$ as you did from the fact that $|S^G|=|S|(\mod p)$

Comment: And how did you know that there is such $S^G$ that exists?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf, I'd don't follow you. In words: $\,S^G\,$ is the subset of $\,S\,$ of all elements there that are fixed by all the elements of $\,G\,$ . The claim I wrote shows that if $\,p\nmid |S|\,$ then there is *at least* one element fixed by all the group, and **for this** element is true $\,G_a=G\,$...but definitely *not* for all the elements of $\,S\,$ !

Comment: So how exactly do you know that there is at least one elt fixes by all the group. I guess this is the part I don't understand.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Oh and I also edit my question, maybe it makes better sense now, I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check my last comment under your question, from that lemma it follows that there **must exist** $\,a\in S\,$ s.t. $\,ga=a\;,\;\;\forall\,g\in G\,$ (why?).

For this very particular $\,a\in S\,$ it is certainly true that $\,G_a=G\,$ ...:)